# Select a dynamic range from active cell in Google Sheets and hide

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google App Script, so please be gentle with me, I have a set of values from cells E12:E20. I want to select the range, then iterate through the selection and when it finds a 1 make that the active cell and select from there to cell E20 and hide the rows in the selection.  I can do this in VBA like this:

```
Range("E12:e21").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
Range(ActiveCell, "e20").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Range("e8").Activate
```

However, I don't know how to do it in App Script, this is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. I'm specially stuck on the iteration part

```
function selectRange() {
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = activeSheet.getActiveSheet();  
var rangeList = activeSheet.getRangeList(['e12:e21']);
rangeList.activate();
  
  
var cell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell(); 
var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  
 while (cellValue != 0) {
    cell = cell.offset(1, 0);
    cellValue = cell.getValue(); 
   cell.activate();
   }  
  }
```

Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to make? Do you want to delete the numbers or just hiding them? Are there any other cells filled in the sheet? If so it would be better to delete the cell values since you can hide entire rows or columns but nor a specific cell.

Comment: I'm trying to hide the rows that have been selected. Yes there other cells that are filled in the sheet, that is why I just want to hide the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- Look for the number `1` in the range `E12:E20` from your active sheet.
- If `1` is found in the range, hide all the rows from the one that contains `1` until row 20.

Doing this does not require activating a range every time. You can work with a cell (retrieve its value, edit it, etc.) without it being active.

#### Solution:

You just need to do the following:

- Retrieve the range `E12:E20`. You can use [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) for that.
- After retrieving the range values via [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), look for the index in which `1` first appears. You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for that.
- If `1` is found, use the `index` retrieved in last step to hide the corresponding rows via [Sheet.hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex,-numrows).

#### Code snippet:

```
function hideRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstRow = 12;
  var lastRow = 20;
  var range = sheet.getRange("E" + firstRow + ":E" + lastRow);
  var index = range.getValues().findIndex(val => val[0] == 1);
  if (index != -1) {
    var firstRowToHide = firstRow + index;
    var numRowsToHide = lastRow - firstRowToHide + 1;
    sheet.hideRows(firstRowToHide, numRowsToHide);
  }
}
```